# $http.get to resource in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-resource

How would i change the following code form $http.get to a $resource

```
//The created resource (not using it for now)
hq.factory('LogsOfUser', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/HQ/Graph/GetLoggedinTimes?userName=:userName', {
        userName: '@userName'
    })
});

//The Controller
var ModalViewLogActionsCtrl = function ($scope, $http, $log, LogsOfUser, $modal) {
    $scope.openLogs = function (userName) {
        $http.get("/HQ/Graph/GetLoggedinTimes?userName=" + userName).success(function (data) {
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'LogView.html',
                controller: 'ModalLogViewInstance',
                resolve: {
                    items: function () {
                        //$scope.items = data;
                        $log.log(data);
                        $scope.items = data;
                        return $scope.items; //return data;
                    },
                    userName: function () {
                        return userName;
                    }
                }
            });
        }).error(function () {
            alert("eror :(");
        });;
    };
};
```

Comment: I'm facing the use of multiple resources in a controller. If i use multiple $http.get, i'll have problems to keep my solution clean and i don't think it's the correct way. Using resources solely resources should be a cleaner alternative

Answer (score 0):

You've already done most of the work. All you need now is to call the service inside the controller :

```
LogsOfUser.query({
    userName: userName
}, function success(data) {
    //your code
}, function err() {
    alert("Error")
});
```

Use `query` to get an array of data, and `get` to get a single document.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example how to call a resource from a controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $resource) {
   var userName = 'Bob';
   var LoggedinTimes = $resource('/HQ/Graph/GetLoggedinTimes');
   var data = LoggedinTimes.get({userName : userName}, function () {
        console.log(data);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you would want to move data-related logic behind a Service, so your controller doesn't know about server-specifics. More importantly, your Service becomes reusable as all services in AngularJS are global singletons. your controller stays small, as it should be.

Next, your controller would call `getLoggedIntimes()` and work with the outcome *as if the data is there*. The result of a `$resource.get()` or similar functions return an empty object or array which fills itself when the REST call returns with data.

In your service you would do the actual `$resource.get()`.

something along the lines of the following pseudo code:

```
//The Controller
var ModalViewLogActionsCtrl = function ($scope, MyService, $log, LogsOfUser, $modal) {
    $scope.openLogs = function (userName) {
        var items = MyService.getLoggedInTimes(userName);

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'LogView.html',
            controller: 'ModalLogViewInstance',
            resolve: {
                items: function () {
                    $scope.items = items;
                    return $scope.items;
                },
                userName: function () {
                    return userName;
                }
            }
        });

    };
};


app.service('MyService', function ($resource) {
    var loggedInResource = $resource('/HQ/Graph/GetLoggedinTimes/:userName');

    return {
        getLoggedInTimes: functio(username) {
            return loggedInResource.get({
                username: username
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: This seems like the most logical code, i do find it weird that all the information that goes into defining the $resource is actually repeated in the service instead of calling the name ( in this case: LogsOfUser), it's calling the Url.